# Show filename and line number for Capybara Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

In my Cucumber steps, I'm using `page.evaluate_script` to interact with Javascript on the page.

I've recently run into the following error:

```
this.results is null (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnexpectedJavascriptError)
./features/step_definitions/my_web_steps.rb:11:in `/^I select "([^"]*)" from the results     list$/'
features/run_tournament.feature:24:in `And I select "Steve Smith" from the results list'
```

Capybara gives me Javascript error message and a stack trace in the ruby code, but no information about where in the Javascript code this error occurs.

Is there I way I can get it to show me the filename and line number where the Javascript error occurred?

Answer (score 1):

[This thread in the capybara google group](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/d08576cbbc90d282/3ff1e2724c5dd024) has a few ideas, such as using culerity instead of selenium because culerity has an option for raising JS errors and getting firefox to log to a file.

The only other thing I can think of is to install firebug in the firefox profile that selenium uses, then calling a step like "Then I sleep for 30 seconds" (defining that in your step definitions of course) right where you know a javascript error is and then looking at the error in firebug.

Good luck!